# Maximum URL length with System.Net.HttpListener (C#)

Tags: c#, http, httplistener

I have written a simple server using System.Net.HttpListener in C# via the following code:

```
Listener = new HttpListener();
Listener.Prefixes.Add(Prefix);
Listener.Start();
Listener.BeginGetContext(GetContextCallback, null);
```

I have noticed that my server returns a 400 (Bad Request) HTTP response whenever the URL I send (in the HTTP GET) is over ~255 characters. I have done some research on this and it seems that there is no standard, though most browsers and servers seem to handle at least ~2000 characters.

The funny thing is my GetContextCallback() is never even being called when it fails this way.

I really would like to figure out how to configure this to support larger than 255 characters, does anyone know if is possible?

Thanks!

Update: I discovered this limitation doesn't appear to be on the entire URL, but rather on an individual directory name. I'm guessing this has something to do with MAX_PATH, but I know for a fact other servers can handle this, and I have seen actual links "in the wild" that have directory names that are 300+ characters (Google in particular for links like /extern_js/f/........).

Update: I am testing my server with telnet, using the following GET request:

```
GET /013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789013456789/test.html
Host: 10.15.38.80:8008
Accept: */*
```

Comment: I just tested from a browser with a string of over 800 characters and it worked fine.  Can you post the code you are using for your HTTP GET?

Comment: I am actually not using code to test, I am using telnet. I updated my original post to contain a path that breaks HttpListener (with 400 return code).

Comment: You are right, it is definitely a folder limitation.  It seems some sites support it (I can post that URL to google.com no problem), but others don't (Microsoft.com returns an Invalid URL error).  The question becomes, do you really need that much information in the folder name?  If you just add 1 subfolder and split it in half, it still works.  I would recommend keeping the folder level small and putting the data in the querystring.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be any other way but setting a value in the registry.

Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters and create a DWORD (32 bit) parameter named UrlSegmentMaxLength. Set the value to 0 and you won't be bothered with long url issues anymore.

You have to restart before the change is applied.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129